# want asp dropdownlist selection to make panel visible

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, ddl, visible

I have an asp dropdownlist that I would like to make a panel visible if the selection contains a certain word- how would this be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets say you have dictionary like this

```
List<string> words = new List<string>();
words.Add("foo");
```

then onchange event of drop down list

```
string selectedText = ddlPanel.SelectedText;
foreach(var w in words)
{
 if ( w.Contains(selectedText)
  {
     pnl.Visible = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select onchange="if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value.indexOf('foo') != -1) document.getElementById('panel').style.display = 'block'">
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the panel you're looking to hide within an update panel, and use the dropdownlist change as a trigger to the updatepanel. On the update, check the dropdownlist's value and set the visibility.

Either that, or if you know the ID of the panel you can manually use javascript and bind the change event to a function that checks the values and shows/hides the panel accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Create dropDownlist with two items, "visible" and "not visible" or whatever suits you and make sure to set the autopostback property to true.
Then in vb write the following on page load:

```
If ddlMydropdown.Text = "visible" then
   panelId.Visible = true
else
   panelId.Visible = false
End If
```

If you code in c#, you can convert this vb code to c# over at [developerfusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/)